# How to use a filter on this code so that I get a list of versions in the descending order?

Tags: angularjs, html, filter, angular-filters

```
<select id="qa-KCdropdown2"
                class="dftdropdown label-default left"
                data-ng-model="selectedVersion"
                data-ng-show="currentProductVersions.length > 0"
                data-ng-options="version.version for version in currentProductVersions">
            <option value="">Select Version</option>
</select>
```

My versions are in this format: 
4.0.1
9.0.1
10.0.1
11.2.3

I need to list these with latest on the top.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter, and inside that filter you can create a custom sort function that you pass to `[array].sort(fnc);`

```
app.filter('sortByVersion', function() {
    return function (list) {
        return list.sort(function (a, b) {
            // expand these 2 lines to strip out all other non-numeric characters if needed
            var vA = parseInt(a.replace('.', ''));
            var vB = parseInt(b.replace('.', ''));
            return vB - vA;
        });
    };
});
```

Then your HTML:

```
<select id="qa-KCdropdown2"
            class="dftdropdown label-default left"
            data-ng-model="selectedVersion"
            data-ng-show="currentProductVersions.length > 0"
            data-ng-options="version.version for version in currentProductVersions | sortByVersion">
        <option value="">Select Version</option>
</select>
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OeSZ4zmrvKJEJwhwdO11?p=preview